# Tracking / Throttling external API calls for SendGrid (C#)

Tags: c#, api, sendgrid

I'm building a prototype MVP app with backend in ASP.Net / WebAPI. It is setup with the standard Asp.Net identity provider for user account creation.

I've added an Email Service and hooked it up to SendGrid following [this](https://bitoftech.net/2015/02/03/asp-net-identity-2-accounts-confirmation-password-user-policy-configuration) tutorial to support:

1. Send "Confirm Email" message
2. Send "Password Reset" message.

I'm on the free SendGrid package - 100 msgs per day which I'm unlikely to reach anytime soon - however, I'd still like to add some functionality to track and limit calls to 100 per day. Also to prevent the same user to keep requesting email confirmation / password resets for more than say 5 per day - what would be the best strategy to do this?

I was thinking to create a DB Table:

`|Date | User | MessageType`

- When method to send confirm email or password reset is called, check total rows for the day is less than 100 and total messages for given user is less than say 10.
- If so, make the API call to send the email and then update the table
- If not just return an error message to the client app saying to try again later (although not ideal, should be sufficient for the initial stages).

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: "Also to prevent the same user to keep requesting email confirmation / password resets for more than say 5 per day - what would be the best strategy to do this?" Have a running total of "Password Reset Attempts" right next to the email in the Backend Database. Same way you track failed login attemts. If you do get enough users that you reach the limit, you will need a different plan anyway.

Comment: Thanks will look into adding that to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes DB table is good enough. Though, instead of counting the rows you can have a column to update the count itself. Other wise there is chance of growing the size of the table and it can delay the method.